# Is it possible to "lock" view of a XsltListViewWebPart?

Tags: permissions, list-view

Is it possible to disable users from using or making new views for my ListView?

I want to be able to use a view not showing "secret" colums, and be sure the user cant change the view to be able  to se the "secret" view.

Answer (score 2):

You need to adapt the base-permissions of the permissionlevel.
There is a base-permission: "Manage Personal Views". Remove it for all groups you don't want to create new views.

To remove permissions of users to create public views, remove the "Manage Lists" basepermission.

If you don't want users to switch between views, that's more difficult, because you can't set permissions on views...

Comment: This sounds like the best approach so far. Their may not be any permission levels for views, but if I remember correct you can make a private view? Couldn't it be possible to make the view containing the "secret" fields appear as "private views" for the users with the right permission levels?

Answer (score 0):

You can read answers to [my questions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22526/create-security-field). There is a discussion how to create "secret" fields.