# How to not show cloumns when I adding a something to one of my custom list

Tags: list

I have a custom list i developed my selfg, i also created a view for it. One view for normal users another for admins. When you go to add something new to the list the fields I want to hide from normal users are there. Is there a setting somewhere to fix or change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22526/create-security-field) seems to have an answer that might pertain to your situation.

I advise that you create another list with different security settings and then create lookup columns that pull information from that list. In this way only the individuals with access to the other list (the one being "looked up") will be able to see it. I haven't tried it myself however.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this link useful:
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2011/09/hide-sharepoint-list-field-based-on.html

Comment: Nadeem; that JQuery code can *definitely* be useful for displaying dashboard information, etc. Just be mindful that JQuery does not provide any *real* security. If a user is smart enough they will still be able to view the full list or find the source URL of the list that is being filtered. But your code could definitely have some great implementation value!